# controlling media volume through volume button inside the Ionic 3 app when the sound is not playing

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

My App will play sound only for 2 to 3 seconds. I tried to increase the sound when the sound is not playing, but phone increased and decreased only the phone volume not the media volume. media volume is changing only when I try to increase or decrease when the sound is playing. is there any possibility to control the media volume from APP itself without any need to sound to play.

Native Audio plugin is used to play the sounds.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem here, did you find a solution? Thanks